# Inserting static current time in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a time log spreadsheet.  I have a new sheet for each day.  In each sheet, I have a transactional record of how my time was spent.  When I start or end a task, I usually type in the time ("11:00 AM" for example).

Is there a shortcut to inserting the current time into a field?  I'm sure it can be done with a macro, but I'm not very knowledgeable about macros.  I'd like to simply highlight a field and hit some sort of shortcut key to insert a static value of the current time.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Select the cell you want to enter the time, and hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>:</kbd> keys at the same time on the keyboard. This keyboard shortcut will instruct Excel to enter a static time into the selected cell.

Comment: Luck is on my side today ;)

Comment: Strictly speaking it's the semi-colon (;), rather than a colon (:) although they are on the same key.

Comment: @w3d: On my keyboard (TR-type), they are on different keys. When I use the colon (:) I get the time, and when I use the semicolon (;) I get the date.

Comment: @Mike C.: You're more than welcome.

Comment: @Mehper Ah OK I see. It's the MS docs that are a bit misleading! Do you need to press SHIFT to get a semi-colon as well?

Comment: @w3d: Yes, I hold SHIFT to type semicolon. I agree with you about MS docs are misleading. They should correct their help files and pages. I just checked Excel's help file and it's the same as the one on their web page.

Comment: @Mehper On a UK/US keyboard I _don't_ hold SHIFT to type a semicolon. For me, Excel's help file is not quite the same as [the web page that gets served to me](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/insert-the-current-date-and-time-in-a-cell-HP003056107.aspx). Excel's help is correct. I imagine the web page is locale specific so I assume you will be seeing something different to me, since the page I see does not include SHIFT for the semicolon (only for the colon)?

Comment: On a US keyboard I get semicolon = date and colon = time.  That is to say, Ctrl+; = date, Ctrl+Shift+; (aka Ctrl+:) = time.

Answer (score 8):

Insert a static date or time:

**Current date:** Select a cell and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>

**Current time:** Select a cell and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>

**Current date and time:** Select a cell and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> then <kbd>SPACE</kbd> then <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>

[Source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/insert-the-current-date-and-time-in-a-cell-HP003056107.aspx).

Comment: BTW, for anyone hoping these work in Word, they don't.